# append overwriting dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function which is called each time a message is received, I am trying to append information to a dataframe as it comes in, but when I open it I only see the final message to be received is in the dataframe.

My code is below

```
def on_message(client, userdata,  message):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    topic = message.topic
    new_row = {'message':message, 'topic': topic}
    df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: are you returning the df in your function to the original df in your code? otherwise your code won't know that the df has changed, as this will only be known within your function and in the output.csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first load your CSV file and append new contents to it
and then you overwrite new dataframe to CSV file

```
import os.path

def on_message():
    
    file_exist_check=os.path.isfile('output.csv')
    # print(file_exist_check)
    # False
    
    if file_exist_check==False:
      # Note that you need to use [] for your data like ['msg1'] to avode following error
      # ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
      d={'message':['mgs1'],
         'topic':['tp1']}
      new_df=pd.DataFrame(d)
      new_df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
    else:
      # Load existing CSV file
      loaded_csv=pd.read_csv('output.csv',encoding='utf-8')
      # print(loaded_csv)
      #   message topic
      # 0    msg1   tp1
      # 1    msg2   tp2

      # Create new row
      new_row = {'message':'msg3', 'topic': 'tp3'}

      # Append new row to your CSV file
      df = loaded_csv.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
      # print(df)
      #   message topic
      # 0    msg1   tp1
      # 1    msg2   tp2
      # 2    msg3   tp3

      # Overwrite existing output.csv by new above df
      df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

on_message()
```

Comment: Works well, is there a way to do this without having to create the file first?

Comment: @Michael Do you mean you want to suppose the situation when you don't have CSV file first? Then, if there is no file, you can create one then append data to existing CSV file. I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line `df = pd.Dataframe()`. You are defining the dataframe again, so it is always an empty DF that gets the new message appended.

Instead change the function to take the df as an input, and then append to that:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, message, df):
    topic = message.topic
    new_row = {'message':message, 'topic': topic}
    df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv('output.csv')
```